# Linq2SQL choose IDs where join returns negative

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am attempting to query for an ID from table that needs to be joined with a negative result. In other words choose all the ScacIDs where that ScacID is not present in the joined table ScacSetup. This query returns no result.

```
var tasksNotAssociated = from scac in db.Scacs
                         where !db.ScacSetupTasks.Any(s => s.ScacTaskID == taskID)
                         group scac by scac.ScacCode into scacNotAssociated
                         select scacNotAssociated.FirstOrDefault();
```

[image: My Table to join and choose where ScacID not present]

Comment: Left join + `Where leftSide == null`?

Comment: OK, lemme try it.  Thanks for the speedy answer.

Comment: an example would make you my hero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great and yes my solution was to use the left join that was provided by my navigation property; ScacSetupTasks.  Guess I should have posted my navigation property and tagged with Entity Framework. OK, here is what I found to work and is essentially a left join where leftside == null as suggested by MarcinJeraszek, thanks buddy.

```
var scacsNotAssociated = db.Scacs.Where(s => s.ScacSetupTasks.Count(sst => sst.ScacTaskID == taskID) == 0);
```